# ASP dynamic data url?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I've been quite frustrated since I have been looking on google for an answer to my problem and nothing pops up, I am using dynamic data to create some forms on a asp.net website however on one field I want to be able to include a hyperlink to another page, is this possible ? if so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Code

```
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display( Name = "1. Help Page Document", Order = 1)]
        [ChoiceComment("No", "Yes")]
        [ChoiceDisplayValues("No", "Yes")]
        [ChoiceValues("2", "1")]
        [RadioListOrientation(RadioListOrientation.EnumOrientation.Horizontal)]
        [UIHint("RadioButtonList")]
```

so I want the text '**Help Page Document**' to be a url like an anchor tag, is this possible? via javascript, c#, etc... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.
One way is to change the **field template** that you currently use the this field or you can create a new one like EmailAddress.ascx below.

For an example, in your project, look at the content of :  /DynamicData/FieldTemplates/ForeignKey.ascx

See also : https://goo.gl/7HZ4c6
To use this example, you will need to put the following annotation in your meta data :
**[FilterUIHint("EmailAddress")]**